# flutter - how to random widget sequence/order

Tags: android, user-interface, flutter, widget, flutter-layout

Let's say I have below widget:

```
ListView(
   physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
   shrinkWrap: true,
   children: <Widget>[

     this.widgetA();
     this.widgetB();
     this.widgetC();

     this.widgetX();
     this.widgetY();
     this.widgetZ();

   ]
)
```

Is there a way to random  the order of widget X, Y and Z, so the order will be Y, Z, X or Z, X, Y while widget A, B, C remain the same (no random).

Is this possible?

===Update

What's this warning means?

[image]

in `...randomOrderedWidgets,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with Flutter but rather Dart. You can create a new list called `randomOrderedWidgets`, `shuffle` it, and then use the spread operator or concatenation of the lists to include it as part of the `ListView` children.

```dart
final randomOrderedWidgets = [
    this.widgetX(),
    this.widgetY(),
    this.widgetZ()
];
randomOrderedWidgets.shuffle();

ListView(
   physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
   shrinkWrap: true,
   children: <Widget>[
     this.widgetA(),
     this.widgetB(),
     this.widgetC(),
   ]..addAll(randomOrderedWidgets)
)
```

Comment: hi, thanks but i got a warning, see updated question. what's this mean?  anyway, your method is working. Thank you

Comment: @anunixercoder Ah, yes the spread operator is only supported in Dart 2.2.2 and as it states and the flutter runtime shouldn't be restricted to that version. I have updated the answer with an alternative. I haven't run the code but something like that should work